# Rebuild database views

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

When you create a view, the column structure of the view is created and stored, and thus you can see it in object explorer:

[image: Picture 1]

When you alter the source data tables, sometimes things go wacky, because the view may have been built with "Select *" yet the schema created for you has the old information without the additional columns.

Does SQL Server have an easy way to rebuild the view schemas?

Comment: I think i can drop and recreate, but checking if there is something easier... because when you have complicated dependencies on the views, you have to create them in a certain order...

Comment: Nothing goes "wacky" this is by design. When you `CREATE` (or `ALTER`) a `VIEW` you define the columns at that point. If you (foolishly) use `*` then the columns **currently** available will be used. If you change the definition of the tables underneath that doesn't change the definition of the `VIEW`; it's already been defined.

Comment: If you change the schema of the underlying tables which are exposed by the view, execute `sp_refreshview`, specifying the name of the view to refresh the meta-data.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `SELECT *` in views.  I say this as someone who has spent much too much time (in the past) debugging views that had this "feature".

When you do create a view in a production system, create it with [`SCHEMABINDING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> SCHEMABINDING
>
> Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition. The view definition itself must first be modified or dropped to remove dependencies on the table that is to be modified.

Although this adds an extra step when trying to modify tables, the increased resilience of the system is worth it.